# HTML Pdf converter working fine in windows but not in linux using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, pdf-generation

I am using NodeJS library html-pdf-node. This is working fine in windows but getting error in Linux operating system.

Getting the following error:

```
    (node:25675) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental
    (node:25675) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
```

Source Code:

```
var html_to_pdf = require('html-pdf-node');
    var number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000000000000) + 1);
    let options = { format: 'A4', args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'] };
    var outputFile = "./dist/assets/analysisReport/pdf_" + number + "temp.pdf";
    let file = { content: request.body.html };
    html_to_pdf.generatePdf(file, options).then(pdfBuffer => {
        fs.writeFile(outputFile,pdfBuffer, function (err) {
            if (err) { console.log(err) }
            else {
                response.json({ success: 1, outputFile: "/assets/analysisReport/pdf_" + number + "temp.pdf"});
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Welcome! Please attach your error and not only your source code!

Comment: Do you have chromium browser installed on your system? Look at puppeteer help: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#running-on-alpine